# WebStorm/PhpStorm: How to disable typo check for specific type of strings?

Tags: phpstorm, webstorm, jetbrains-ide

I really like that WebStorm and PhpStorm IDEs from JetBrains will check for typos in my code. The problem I have is that throughout the codebase, I have hundreds of random strings formatted like this: `[XXXXXX]` where `X` is an alphanumeric character (0-9 or A-Z). The IDE informs me that these are typos and these false-positive warnings make real typos difficult to find.

[image]

I don't know how to tell the IDE to ignore these strings.  I've considered:

1. Adding the strings to the dictionary: this carries a high overhead because there are hundreds, and as the codebase expands there will be hundreds and eventually thousand+ more
2. Disabling typo check: this isn't a good solution because I still want the IDE to alert me of typos

Is there a good solution to this?  Maybe a setting to consider all strings that fit a particular RegEx as valid, or to ignore typo checks for all such strings?

Comment: `Settings/Preferences | Editor | Inspections | Proofreading | Typo` -- that the best you can do in terms of config -- 3 options there + a standard thingy -- make a custom scope (e.g. include certain files/folders only) and disable this inspection for that scope. The only other option is to suppress that inspection for that particular element (which adds PHPDoc like comment just before that -- the downside: it pollutes your code with such useless otherwise comments).

Comment: Thanks @LazyOne. I'm sorry to say that these suggestions are not a good fit for me. The strings are dispersed in almost all code files, and they appear within larger text that I want typo-checked so disabling the inspection is a net negative in my case.

Comment: Please open Settings/preferences | Editor | Natural Languages | Grammar > disable "String literals" checkbox for PHP (if we're talking about PHP)

Comment: @Dmitrii wouldn't that disable all string literal checks?  I still need my strings checked; I just want to figure out how to tell the IDE that `[XXXXXX]` where `X` is `/[0-9A-F]/` is not a typo

Comment: @BeetleJuice yes, it would :( There's no such setting in IDE, unfortunately. You can share your concerns at https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-273746

Comment: Other tickets that are related: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-160183, https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-242239, https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-243261 (aggregator ticket). RegEx exclusions: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-159617